# how to get variable from tkinter class based widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-class

I am using a class-based Tkinter widget:

Here is the relevant code:

```
class PseudostreamWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw
        self.targetIP = tk.Entry(self.Ipconfig)
        self.targetIP.configure(background='black', font='{Lato} 12 {}', foreground='white', highlightbackground='black')
        _text_ = '''Friend's Public IP Here'''
        self.targetIP.delete('0', 'end')
        self.targetIP.insert('0', _text_)
        #target_ip = ??????????????????????????????
```

I want `target_ip` to be the variable that I can use in my program but I just don't know how to get a variable here.

I have tried:

```
target_ip = self.targetIP
```

and I thought that would work but it doesn't, also, what should I be reading up on, this seems really rudimentary what part have I missed? Please link me to the docs!

Comment: Did you forget to `.pack`/`.grid` `self.targetIP`?

Comment: I have the grid thing - self.targetIP.grid(column='1', row='0').
can I use that somehow?

Comment: Anywhere in this class, you can use `self.targetIP.get()` to retrieve the contents of your Entry.  There's no point in doing this inside the `__init__()` method, as the user hasn't had a chance to enter anything yet.

Comment: oh, okay, thanks I will give that a shot, yea, I didn't realize that my bad! I just full-on went tunnel vision lol!

Comment: @jasonharper I am so sorry, but could you show me how to do this?? my complete code - https://codeshare.io/5zZq94

Comment: Where do you want this `target_ip` to be, and why are you defining it.

Comment: @CoolCloud  I am making a mock video chat application and to connect to my friends' computer I will need his IP which means I will have to make a text input field for him and I have done all the backend I am just having a hard time trying to get the text input from a class-based view into as a variable so that i can use it as the Ip of my friend's computer, you can have a look at the code for the GUI here - https://codeshare.io/5zZq94 (its my first time making a gui)

Comment: Dont stress over it much, watch a tutorial and understand the basics

Comment: I solved it, thanks!